# Ошибка multiple definition of и прочее

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

Начал изучать WxWidgets. Надо создать XYZArray через WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY и WX_DEFINE_OBJARRAY. Но вот что-то не выходит, хотя делал всё, как в документации.

```
#ifndef WXPOINTS_H_INCLUDED
#define WXPOINTS_H_INCLUDED

//#include "xyz.h"
#include <wx/dynarray.h>

class XYZ;
WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY(XYZ, XYZArray);

class XYZ
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    //void print();
};
#include <wx/arrimpl.cpp>
WX_DEFINE_OBJARRAY(XYZArray);

class wxPoints
{
public:
    wxPoints();
    XYZArray arr;
    void Test();
};


#endif // WXPOINTS_H_INCLUDED
```

Выкидывает ошибки:
[image: Собственно, ошибки]

Answer (score 2):

Исходник, в котором определяется XYZArray подключается два раза. Не следует подключать CPP-файлы через include, а в H-файлах должна быть проверка на повторное включение.

Comment: А как оно всё же должно быть? Можете, пожалуйста, написать?

Comment: Надо просто все объявления собирать в H-файлах, а реализацию — в одноимённых CPP-файлах. К примеру, описывается класс XYZArray. Тогда `XYZArray.h` будет содержать `#ifndef XYZArray_h #define XYZArray_h`, затем объявление класса и `#endif`. Это "защитит" файл от повторного включения. А определения методов класса располагаются в `XYZArray.cpp`, и этот файл никуда не включается: везде, где потребуется класс XYZArray, в шапке файла дописывается `#include "XYZArray.h"`. Вот и всё, никакой магии.

Comment: Зачем пугать новичков сложными конструкциями? Достаточно написать #pragma once в начале каждого header'а, он придерживается огромным числом компиляторов.

Comment: Там дело больше не в конкретных строках, а в принципе размещения объявлений и определений. Я просто привёл каноничное решение. `#pragma once` — нестандарт, поэтому, видимо, я изредка встречал его в листингах, но не в учебной литературе. Живу вчерашним днём. :)